# how to set RewriteRule in kubernetes ingress?

Tags: kubernetes, mod-rewrite

is it possible to set RewriteRule in kubernetes ingress?

here is my nginx VirtualHost settings

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/hello/?$ /mydirectory.index.html [L]
</VirtualHost>
```

then I would like to set the same RewriteRule in ingress

```
    kind: Ingress
    metadata:
    annotations:
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
        RewriteRule ^/hello/?$ /mydirectory/index.html [L] // something like this!
    spec:
    rules:
        - host: "hello.com"
        http:
            paths:
            - path: /
                backend:
                serviceName: myService
                servicePort: 80
                rewriteRules:
                - '^/hello/?$ /mydirectory/index/html [L]' // something like this!
```

Comment: Do you know what kind of Ingress Controller is deployed on your cluster. Haproxy, nginx, traefik, ambassador, ... ? There's some lack of standardization, beyond picking exposed service and FQDN. You first need to figure this out. Meanwhile, the first snippet you call "Nginx" is obviously an Apache VirtualHost. your nginx annotation including something like this definitely won't work

Answer (score 1):

look at the nginx ingress controller documentation [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/). There are example configurations and explanations on how to set rewrite rule on kubernetes ingress resource.